# Wrong simplification of a function?

Tags: analysis

I have 2 functions $f_1(x_1), f_2(x_2)$ and need to find the maximum of adding both functions, where $x_1 + x_2 = 50$.

$f_1(x) = -0.001x^3+0.07x^2+5.9x-65$

$f_2(x) = -0.001x^3+0.07x^2+5.8x-20$

I have defined $f_3$ as $f_3(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(50-x)$ like this:

$f_3(x) = -0.001x^3+0.07x^2+5.9x-65+(-0.001*(50-x)^3+0.07*(50-x)^2+5.8*(50-x)-20)$

Then I have simplified $f_3$ and have come to this:

$f_{3 simpl}(x) = -0.01x^2 - 0.6x + 255$

The trouble is, if I plot both functions $f_3, f_{3 simpl}$, I get very different plots.

Can someone see where I made the error?

Thanks you,

Ingo

Comment: I can see immediately that the cubic term is wrong. Try simplifying the combination again.

Comment: Thanks, that was a typing error, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get: $f_3(x)=255+0.6x-0.01x^2$.

Comment: Thank you, that was fast, and you are right, this way it is correct, now on to find where I went wrong.